# Sort frequency distribution of string using rank (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have to sort the frequency distribution of a string variable (education) using predetermined ranks and the code I made is below. However, it still sorts using alphabetical (please find image attached), I don't know what went wrong.

```
education_rank = {' Bachelors':12, ' HS-grad':8, ' 11th':6, ' Masters':14, ' 9th':5, ' Some-college':11, ' Assoc-acdm':10, ' Assoc-voc':9, ' 7th-8th':4, ' Doctorate':15, ' Prof-school':13, ' 5th-6th':3, ' 10th':16, ' 1st-4th':2, ' Preschool':1, ' 12th':7}

fd_education = pd.value_counts(adult_data.education)
print(fd_education)
    
fd_education = fd_education.sort_index(level='education_rank')
print(fd_education)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Try this method -**

1. Sort the `education_rank` as a series to get index values
2. Use index values to fetch rows from the `value_counts` series
3. `Dropna` if any

```
#Your predefined rankings
education_rank = {'Bachelors':12, 'HS-grad':8, '11th':6, 'Masters':14, '12th':77}

#Your frequency output from value_counts()
fd_education = pd.Series({'Bachelors':500, 'HS-grad':809, '11th':23, 'Masters':65})

fd_education[pd.Series(education_rank).sort_values().index].dropna()
```

```
11th          23
HS-grad      809
Bachelors    500
Masters       65
dtype: int64
```

---

**Explanation -**

The issue is that you are passing a dictionary to the level instead of the index name of the series object. The goal of level to help with multi-index situations. This lets it decide which of the indexes to sort on. You cant provide sequence as a list/dict to sort on.

If it is unable to find the index name you have provided, it will just resort to sorting by alphabetical order. Check this example -

```
#Your predefined rankings
education_rank = {'Bachelors':12, 'HS-grad':8, '11th':6, 'Masters':14, '12th':77}

#Your frequency output from value_counts()
fd_education = pd.Series({'Bachelors':500, 'HS-grad':809, '11th':23, 'Masters':65})
    
fd_education = fd_education.sort_index(level='hello') #<---- 
print(fd_education)
```

```
11th          23
Bachelors    500
HS-grad      809
Masters       65
dtype: int64
```

Do read [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for more details.